# PreparedStatement is faster in Java, How db do it?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, prepared-statement

I know that PreparedStatement is faster than Statement in Java.

I don't know **How** oracle db server do it.

PreparedStatement gets pre-compiled In database server -> less work.
It's reduce load on database.

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM users u WHERE u.id = ?";
PreparedStatement pstmt = connenction.prepareStatement(sql);
pstmt.setLong(1, userId);
pstmt.executeQuery();
```

The query is cached in the database server, and compile only once? 
If yes, how the database server knows that this query was execute before? 
For how long is it cached?

Comment: The JDBC driver knows how to communicate the statement to the server and gets some kind of handle.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> The query is cached in the database server, and compile only once?

More precisely, the query *plan* is cached on the server. When you run a query, your RDBMS prepares a plan first, then executes it. Preparing a plan requires parsing the query, then analyzing and optimizing it, considering the indexes available and the statistics collected on the participating tables.

> If yes, how the database server knows that this query was execute before?

By comparing the string of the query to other queries available in the cache. Since you use parameterized queries, the other query would be textually identical. Caching is the second major reason<sup>*</sup> to use query parameters: if you were to prepare statements like this

```
// WRONG! Don't do it like this!
String sql = "SELECT * FROM users u WHERE u.id = "+userId;
PreparedStatement pstmt = connenction.prepareStatement(sql);
```

all the performance improvements would be gone, because providing a different `ID` would make it a different query that needs a new plan.

<sup>*</sup> The top reason for parameterizing queries is, of course, avoiding injection attacks.

Comment: How he can compare the string? he have a list with all the previous query? there is a time to leave to this string? how long it will be in the cache?

Comment: @lolo It does not need to be a list - a hash table works much better. Query string serves as a nice hash key for the query plan stored in the table.

Comment: So, when this string will be remove from the hash table?

Comment: @lolo I do not know the specifics about Oracle's rules for keeping cached query plans, but usually a cache entry is thrown away when it hasn't been used in a while (which depends, among other things, on the load of the server) or when the hash table starts taking too much memory. I believe that both these parameters can be configured by DBAs, but I am not sure, because I haven't been using Oracle for some seven years now.

Answer (score 3):

You can think of a `PreparedStatement` as a "cached" statement that will be compiled once on the database server.

When you create the statement, it will be sent to the DB server, which will do the usual syntax checking and determine an efficient execution plan for the query. This way, it can re-use the same execution plan (which is cached as well) for multiple invocations of the same statement.

The key of this cache is the statement itself without its parameter values filled. If the values are explicitly filled in the statement (i.e. you don't fill them using the `set*` methods), then a new execution plan would be accessed in the cache. That's why prepared statements are best used when executing several statements but with different values.

Answer (score 0):

I use Data Source in my project , where query cache is dependent on connection.
Query cache is maintained per connection (default size is 10).
That means if I have 5 connection , per connection latest 10 prepared statements are cached.